# State Names and Line Breaks

Tags: sentence

I had some plaques created and my client had New at the end of one line and Hampshire at the start of the next line. I think it looks bad to split the state name and wondered but the "official" rule is on this situation?

Comment: This is a style issue.  Some styles will seek to avoid it.  (Note that this can be managed in most word processors by using a "non-breaking space", but it's a fiddly thing to use this bit everywhere it might be considered necessary.)